# Срез определённих элементов текстового файла

Tags: python

Нужна помощь, полдня танцевал, ни чего не выходит...

```
<string id="6NLJnGfF" text="Pedro" />      #Пример данных файла
<string id="2Pxq8UqX" text="Vasil" />      #Пример данных файла
<string id="1rzKQbWy" text="Nerd" />       #Пример данных файла
<string id="9s4IP7jB" text="Santiago" />   #Пример данных файла
```

На выводе хочу получить ключ и значение. Пример: 6NLJnGfF = Pedro
 Мой максимум вот это чудо...

```
f = open('test_file.txt').readlines()
d = [str[16:] for str in f]
m = [str[::-1] for str in d] 
v = [str[4:] for str in m]
m = [str[::-1] for str in v]

with open('new_file.txt','w') as F: 
    F.writelines("%s\n" % i for i in m)
```

Comment: Lxml поможет думаю Вам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
with open('test_file.txt','r') as f_in, open('new_file.txt','w') as f_out: 
    while True:
        line_list = f_in.readline().strip().split('"') 
        if not line_list[0]: break
        new_line = f'{line_list[1]} = {line_list[3]}\n'
        f_out.writelines(new_line)

with open('new_file.txt','r') as f_out: 
    text = f_out.read()
print(text)
```